# weird thing about String.intern in Java

Tags: java, string

I am learning Java basic concept recently, when I tried some code samples about `String.intern` there was a weird thing happened. Code below:

Snippet 1(normal):

```
String str1 = new String("0") + new String("0");
str1.intern();
String str2 = "00";
assertTrue(str1 == str2); // pass
assertTrue(str1.equals(str2)); // pass
```

Snippet 2(weird):

```
String str1 = new String("1") + new String("1");
str1.intern();
String str2 = "11";
assertTrue(str1 == str2); // fail; what happened???
assertTrue(str1.equals(str2)); // pass
```

Snippet 3(normal):

```
String str1 = new String("2") + new String("2");
str1.intern();
String str2 = "22";
assertTrue(str1 == str2); // pass
assertTrue(str1.equals(str2)); // pass
```

So, I don't understand what happened about `new String("1")`, it's really really confused, I need your help, Thanks a lot!

Comment: What about `assertTrue(str1.equals(str2));`? Does that pass the test?

Comment: `assertTrue(str1.equal(str2)); // pass`

Comment: Nice... Just use `.equals()` for `String`-comparison

Comment: Thank you, deHaar! but I wanna know why `new String("1")` failed by  `==` compare reference address :(

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), the explanation and examples are great

Comment: got it, Thank you sooo much! :)

Comment: Well @deHaar, if you read the answer of the link question, you will see that "_You almost always want to use `Objects.equals()`. In the rare situation where you know you're dealing with interned strings, you can use `==`._". And this question is clearly about testing `String.intern` which use the StringPool. So I would guess this "mistake" was done on purpose.

Comment: @AxelH You are right, most likely, I was just not sure about it being *on purpose*, so asked about the comparison.

Comment: @Martin, for your problem. it should be valid. "11" is added in the pool (with intern) so this statement should be correct since you get `str2` without using the constructor. What bother me is that your code can't compile. The method is `equals`, not `equal`.
Is there more to the ode than this ? Not sure of what happen if your overload the pool (everything have a limit...)

Comment: @AxelH Sorry, wrong spell. it should be `equals`. Thank you for your answer.  My English is poor and I'm glad you understand my problem. In sense, when `str1 = "11"` and call the `intern` method, then assign `str2 = "11"`, `str1` and `str2` should    
 have the same reference address, sadly  they are difference, I don't know why.

Comment: @AxelH if i write code like `String str1 = (new String("1") + new String("1")).intern();     String str2 = "11"; `, `str1 == str2` are true. that's weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any string which is already in the string literal pool will already have an object and will not be added when you call `str1.intern()` as it is already there.

On starting, the JVM creates thousands of objects and has many objects already in the String literal pool by the time main() is called.

Which strings are already in the pool depends on what code was run before your code.

```
System.out.println("Strings already in the literal pool");
for (char ch = ' '; ch < 127; ch++) {
    String s = Character.toString(ch);
    System.out.println(s + " " + (s != s.intern()));
}
```

prints

```
Strings already in the literal pool
  true
! false
" true
# false
$ false
% true
& true
' true
( false
) false
* true
+ false
, true
- true
. true
/ true
0 false
1 false
2 false
3 false
4 false
5 false
6 false
7 false
8 false
9 false
: true
; false
< true
= false
> false
? false
@ true
A false
B false
C false
D false
E false
F false
G false
H false
I true
J false
K false
L false
M false
N false
O false
P false
Q false
R false
S false
T false
U true
V false
W false
X false
Y false
Z true
[ true
\ false
] true
^ false
_ true
` false
a false
b false
c false
d false
e false
f false
g false
h false
i false
j false
k false
l false
m false
n false
o false
p false
q false
r false
s false
t false
u false
v false
w false
x false
y false
z false
{ false
| true
} false
~ false
```

Comment: Thank you, Peter Lawrey.